# Best Way to find pct change between two values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to sort values based on percent change (for ex.1%)

This is the data which i retrieved from google finance through pandas.

```
                High
 Date           
 2017-05-30    154.43
 2017-05-31    154.17
 2017-06-01    153.33
 2017-06-02    155.45
 2017-06-05    154.45
 2017-06-06    155.81
 2017-06-07    155.98
 2017-06-08    155.54
 2017-06-09    155.19
 Name: High, dtype: float64

 def pct_change(first, second):
       return(second-first) / first*100.00

 arrays = df['High']
 first = 155.81

 gold = None
 for i in arrays:
     if pct_change(first, sorted(arrays)[-1]) < -0.1:
         gold = i
         print('Found gold which is < -0.1 pct : ', gold)
         break
 print(gold)
```

Is their any simple way to perform such sorting and/or is their any more sophisticated way calculating percent change between two values without using the for loop as such?
I want to get Pct change value between two values, i.e. i want to compare `155.81` with other values to find the percent change between two, and if the given condition met, print the value(not percentage).

Comment: df.High.pct_change(). It's already a method. Also df.pct_change(). For whole dataframe

Comment: but i want to compare with a specific value with others, which i think it does not.

Comment: then please add what you think the results should be so we remove as much ambiguity as possible

Comment: Done, see if its clear to understand what am trying to say.